# Two company and probability example?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, combinations

I ran into a problem that seems strange to me.

> Two companies A,B produce a device that with probability $0.05$ and
>   $0.01$ are broken. if  we buy two devices produced by one company
>   with equal probability and the first device be broken, what is the
>   probability of the second device be broken?

Who can show me how my TA reached to  $13/300$ ?

Comment: So, you pick a random company with even probability, buy two devices, and the first you test is broken?

Comment: yes @ThomasAndrews okey

Comment: @ThomasAndrews are you agree with this answer? I think something is wrong ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $K$ the event that the first checked device is broken. Then
$$P(K)=P(A) P(K|A)+P(B)P(K|B)={1\over2}\cdot0.05+{1\over2}\cdot0.01=0.03\ .$$
What we need to know are the conditional probabilities $P(A|K)$, $P(B|K)$. Now
$$P(K)P(A|K)=P(A\cap K)=P(A)(P(K|A)\ ,$$
which implies
$$P(A|K)={P(A)P(K|A)\over P(K)}={{1\over2}\cdot0.05\over0.03}={5\over6}\ ,$$
and similarly
$$P(B|K)={1\over6}\ .$$
Therefore the event $K'$ that the second checked device is broken has probability
$$P(K')=P(A|K)P(K|A)+P(B|K)P(K|B)={5\over6}\cdot 0.05+{1\over6}\cdot0.01={13\over300}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

A breaks 5 times as often as B. So for every 6 broken devices, 5 times it will be A, and 1 time it will be B.

The broken device was created by A with a $\frac{5}{6}$ probability. Multiplying $\frac{5}{6}$ by the chance A will break the next device, $\frac{1}{20}$, gives $\frac{1}{24}$.

Now the broken device has a 1/6 probability of being created by B. So multiplying by the 1/100 probability B will break the next device gives 1/600. Adding, $\frac{1}{600}+\frac{1}{24}$=$\boxed{\frac{13}{300}}$

Comment: How you get 1/20 ?

Comment: A has a 5% chance of breaking its item, which is equal to 5/100 or 1/20